# PHP SESSION is NOT SAME (Not-in-Synced) in load-balanced Servers?

Tags: php, apache, session, session-cookies, load-balancing

just moved to AWS and launched 2 RHEL Servers, load-balanced. And installed Apache and PHP. Thats all. And second is even the image of first server.

But suddenly i just noticed the PHP `$_SESSION` variables are NOT IN SYNCED. Having differently on each.

After i run this:

```
<?php
session_start();

if ( $_GET["setvalue"] ) {
    $_SESSION["sess_test"] = $_GET["setvalue"];
}

echo "session value: ".$_SESSION["sess_test"];
?>
```

Then i assign like:

- http://www.example.com/session.php?setvalue=hello

After i assign the Session Value, and refresh again and again (ofcourse by removing the "`?setvalue=hello`" portion), the same page is showing 2x different values (as i have two load balanced servers) whenever i refresh.

One is showing:

- session value: hello

And next time is showing:

- session value:

After i give the different value again, only one hitting server is showing the last value and other server is still not get updated with the last value.

ANY IDEA PLEASE? :(

Comment: What's your problem? code working good for me

Comment: Just launch 2 Servers, load-balanced. And install Apache and PHP. Thats all. And test if it works.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the default file-based session storage engine, then naturally, you can't load balance them (at least, not without using some kind of [stickiness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040025/difference-between-session-affinity-and-sticky-session)).

What you need is centralized storage for sessions, e.g. using a [database](http://shiflett.org/articles/storing-sessions-in-a-database) or [memcache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884905/using-memcache-as-a-session-store).

See also [PHP sessions in a load balancing cluster - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994935/php-sessions-in-a-load-balancing-cluster-how)

Comment: Huh :S i even don't know. I just moved to AWS and launched 2 RHEL Servers. And installed Apache and PHP. Thats all. And second is even the image of first server :(